# Catch org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue while spy private method

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermockito

I am trying to spy `MyClass` like

```
MyClass myclass = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5));
PowerMockito.doReturn(myclassState)
                .when(myclass, MemberMatcher.method(MyClass .class, "createState", RequestArgs.class));
ResponseArgs responseArgs = myclass.callPublicMethod()
```

I catch MyClassState cannot be returned by callPublicMethod()
callPublicMethod() should return ResponseArgs. Don't see answer in sof for this.

Comment: I have the answer, power mockito doesn't work with juppiter at this moment correctly(

Comment: Correct work with junit 4

Comment: That is ok since PowerMock is a surrender to bad design anyway... ;o)